# pyspark: Convert BinaryType column to ArrayType(FloatType())

Tags: arrays, pyspark, casting, binary

I have a BinaryType() - column in a Pyspark DataFrame which i can convert to an ArrayType() column using the following UDF:

```
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(FloatType()))
def array_from_bytes(bytes):
    return np.frombuffer(bytes,np.float32).tolist()
```

but i wonder if there is a more "spark-y"/built-in/non-UDF way to convert the types? Is there a  "general" way to get the BinaryType() into an ArrayType()? I tried different variations of .cast(), but none of them did succeed.

I´m asking because i have two concerns with the current approach:

1. i need to know beforehand that the "frombuffer" function is the one that needs to be used
2. probably the UDF is not the optimal way to do it from a performance perspective(?)

The BinaryType() column is created by reading it from a JSON file; in the JSON it is stored as a Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the pandas udf function optimizes the UDF execution time:
[PySpark Usage Guide for Pandas with Apache Arrow](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html)

PyArrow library needs to be installed and the below spark configuration needs to be set:

```
# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
```

The change required would be using  pandas_udf as the decorator

```
@pandas_udf(returnType=ArrayType(FloatType()))
def array_from_bytes(bytes):
    return np.frombuffer(bytes,np.float32).tolist()
```